# innerHtml wont modify HTML of container

Tags: javascript, innerhtml

I was doing some project, and I've came across the mistake (most probably) which I don't understand. lines document.getElementById("fields").innerHtml += and all_bars_holder.innerHtml += are actually not adding content to an element. Elements are pretty nice defined (all ID's are correct) and whole JavaScript code is after the HTML, on very bottom of page. By nature, "fields" is an  and all_bars_holder is an . Whole JS code can be see down. Any suggestion about this matter is welcome. Issue is in asd function.

```
<script>
function bubbleSort(a, b) 
{
    var swapped;
    do {
        swapped = false;
        for (var i=0; i < a.length-1; i++) {
            if (a[i] > a[i+1]) {
                var temp = a[i];
            var temp1 = b[i];
                a[i] = a[i+1];
                a[i+1] = temp;
                b[i] = b[i+1];
                b[i+1] = temp1;
                swapped = true;
            }
        }
    } while (swapped);
}


function neg(b)
{
if (b>=0)
{
var a= b;
return a;
}
else
{
var a= Math.abs(b)/2;
return a;
}
}


function asd() 
{

var num_of_datasets = 1; 
var bar_colors = ['gray','red','green']; 
document.getElementById("graph_title").innerHTML = "<b>Yearly look on money income for last 4 years</b>"; 
var holder_height = 600; 
var holder_width = 800; 
var data_values = [];
var limit_values = [];
data_values[1] = ["250", "160", "200", "80"];
limit_values[1] = ["250", "160", "200", "80"];
var text4 = "one"; 
var text3 = "two"; 
var text2 = "three"; 
var text1 = "four"; 




var main_holder = document.getElementById("main_holder_chart"); 
var all_bars_holder = document.getElementById("all_bars_holder");
main_holder.style.width = holder_width; 
main_holder.style.height = holder_height;
document.getElementById("first_bot").style.marginBottom = Math.abs(holder_width - holder_height); 
document.getElementById("graph_title").style.marginTop = Math.abs(holder_width - holder_height);
var width_of_dataset = 100/(num_of_datasets*2);
var fields = document.getElementById("fields");
all_bars_holder.innerHtml = '';
fields.innerHtml = '';

var i = 0;

if(document.getElementById("field"+i.toString()+"1")){
alert("hie1");


} else {

for(i=1; i<num_of_datasets+1; i++)
{



document.getElementById("fields").innerHtml +='<p align="center">First entry: <input type="textfield" id="field'+i.toString()+'1" value="'+data_values[i][0]+'"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Second entry: <input type="textfield" id="field'+i.toString()+'2" value="'+data_values[i][1]+'"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Third entry: <input type="textfield" id="field'+i.toString()+'3" value="'+data_values[i][2]+'"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Fourth entry: <input type="textfield" id="field'+i.toString()+'4" value="'+data_values[i][3]+'"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</p> <p align="center">Limiter1: <input type="textfield" id="field'+i.toString()+'_1" value="'+limit_values[i][0]+'"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Limiter2: <input type="textfield" id="field'+i.toString()+'_2" value="'+limit_values[i][1]+'"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Limiter3: <input type="textfield" id="field'+i.toString()+'_3" value="'+limit_values[i][2]+'"/></p><hr>';
alert("hie");
}
}





for (i=1; i<num_of_datasets+1; i++)
{

all_bars_holder.innerHtml += '<td style="width: '+width_of_dataset.toString()+'%; padding:0;"><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" id="one_dat_chart'+i.toString()+'" align="right" style="width: 20%; height: 80%; text-align: center;"><tr><td style="vertical-align:top"><p id="text'+i.toString()+'1" style="vertical-align: top;"></p></td></tr><tr><td style="vertical-align:bottom;"><div id="flashback'+i.toString()+'" style="position:relative; top:0px; width:100%; max-width:100%; background-color:black; text-align:right; line-height:20px; font-size: 12px; color:white;">Lorem</div><table cellspacing="0" id="two_dat_chart'+i.toString()+'" cellpadding="0" align="center" style="width: 100%; height: 80%; background-color: green; text-align: center;"><tr><td style="vertical-align:top"><p id="text'+i.toString()+'2" style="vertical-align: top;"></p></td></tr><tr><td style="vertical-align:bottom;"><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" id="three_dat_chart'+i.toString()+'" align="center" style="width: 100%; height: 80%; background-color: pink; text-align: center;"><tr><td style="vertical-align:top"><p id="text'+i.toString()+'3" style="vertical-align: top;"></p></td></tr><tr><td style="vertical-align:bottom;"><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" id="four_dat_chart'+i.toString()+'" align="center" style="width: 100%; height: 80%; background-color: brown; text-align: center;"><tr><td style="vertical-align:top"><p id="text'+i.toString()+'4" style="vertical-align: top;"></p></td></tr><tr><td style="vertical-align:bottom;"><p></p></td></tr></table></td></tr></table></td></tr></table></td></tr></table></td><td style="width:25%; padding:0;"><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" id="one_dat_chart'+i.toString()+'_1" align="left" style=" width: 20%; height: 80%; text-align: center;"><tr><td style="vertical-align:top"><p id="text'+i.toString()+'_1" style="vertical-align: top;"></p></td></tr><tr><td style="vertical-align:bottom;"><div id="flashback'+i.toString()+'_1" style="position:relative; top:0px; width:100%; max-width:100%; background-color:black; line-height:20px; font-size: 12px; color:black;">lorem</div><table cellspacing="0" id="two_dat_chart'+i.toString()+'_1" cellpadding="0" align="center" style=" width: 100%; height: 80%; background-color: green; text-align: center;"><tr><td style="vertical-align:top"><p id="text'+i.toString()+'_2" style="vertical-align: top;"></p></td></tr><tr><td style="vertical-align:bottom;"><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" id="three_dat_chart'+i.toString()+'_1" align="center" style=" width: 100%; height: 80%; background-color: pink; text-align: center;"><tr><td style="vertical-align:top"><p id="text'+i.toString()+'_3" style="vertical-align: top;"></p></td></tr><tr><td style="vertical-align:bottom;"><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" id="four_dat_chart'+i.toString()+'_1" align="center" style=" width: 100%; height: 80%; background-color: brown; text-align: center;"><tr><td style="vertical-align:top"><p id="text'+i.toString()+'_4" style="vertical-align: top;">asd</p></td></tr><tr><td style="vertical-align:bottom;"><p></p></td></tr></table></td></tr></table></td></tr></table></td></tr></table></td>';




var FirstBar = document.getElementById("one_dat_chart"+i.toString()+"");
var SecondBar = document.getElementById("two_dat_chart"+i.toString()+"");
var ThirdBar = document.getElementById("three_dat_chart"+i.toString()+"");
var FourthBar = document.getElementById("four_dat_chart"+i.toString()+"");

var FirstBar1 = document.getElementById("one_dat_chart"+i.toString()+"_1");
var SecondBar1 = document.getElementById("two_dat_chart"+i.toString()+"_1");
var ThirdBar1 = document.getElementById("three_dat_chart"+i.toString()+"_1");
var FourthBar1 = document.getElementById("four_dat_chart"+i.toString()+"_1");



SecondBar.style.background = bar_colors[0];
ThirdBar.style.background = bar_colors[1]; 
FourthBar.style.background = bar_colors[2]; 









var var4 = Number(document.getElementById("field"+i.toString()+"4").value); 
var var3 = Number(document.getElementById("field"+i.toString()+"3").value);
var var2 = Number(document.getElementById("field"+i.toString()+"2").value); 
var var1 = Number(document.getElementById("field"+i.toString()+"1").value);


var var11 = Number(document.getElementById("field"+i.toString()+"_1").value); 
var var22 = Number(document.getElementById("field"+i.toString()+"_2").value);
var var33 = Number(document.getElementById("field"+i.toString()+"_3").value);





var text11 = ""; 
var text22 = "";
var text33 = "";

var vars1 = [var4, var3, var2, var1]; 
var max_of_array = Math.max.apply(Math, vars1); 
var min_of_array = Math.min.apply(Math, vars1); 
var vars = [var3, var2, var1]; 
var varss = [var3, var2, var1]; 
var limvars = [var33, var22, var11]; 
var texts = [text3, text2, text1]; 

bubbleSort(vars, texts); 
bubbleSort(varss, limvars); 


var colors = [FourthBar.style.backgroundColor, ThirdBar.style.backgroundColor,SecondBar.style.backgroundColor]; 
bubbleSort(vars, colors);
document.getElementById('legend').innerHTML = "<p style='font-size:24px;'>Legend</p><table style='width: "+holder_height/4+";  border: 4px solid black'><tr><td style='background-color:black; color: white;'></td><td>"+text4+"</td></tr><tr><td style='background-color:"+colors[2]+";'></td><td>"+texts[2]+"</td></tr><tr><td style='background-color:"+colors[1]+";'></td><td>"+texts[1]+"</td></tr><tr><td style='background-color:"+colors[0]+";'></td><td>"+texts[0]+"</td></tr></table>"; //Printing the legend;

FirstBar.style.height = 1; 
SecondBar.style.height= 1;
ThirdBar.style.height= 1;
FourthBar.style.height = 1;




document.getElementById('text'+i.toString()+'2').innerHTML = vars[2]; 
document.getElementById('text'+i.toString()+'4').innerHTML = vars[0];
document.getElementById('text'+i.toString()+'3').innerHTML = vars[1];




if (parseInt(min_of_array, 10)>=0 && max_of_array)
{
var c=0; 
}
else
{
var c = min_of_array + min_of_array;
}






var m = parseInt(main_holder.style.height, 10)/(parseInt(max_of_array, 10)-parseInt(c, 10));
document.getElementById('point_value').innerHTML = m;



var ffs2 = m * neg(vars[2]); 
var ffs4 = m * neg(vars[0]);
var ffs3 = m * neg(vars[1]);







var cl1 = [FourthBar.style.background, ThirdBar.style.background,  SecondBar.style.background]; 
bubbleSort(limvars, cl1); 



var ffs222 = m * neg(limvars[2]); 
var ffs333 = m * neg(limvars[1]);
var ffs444 = m * neg(limvars[0]);




SecondBar1.style.background = cl1[2]; 
ThirdBar1.style.background = cl1[1]; 
FourthBar1.style.background = cl1[0]; 





var kp = m*(vars[2] - var4); 





if (ffs2>(holder_height-10)){ffs2 = ffs2 - (ffs2-holder_height) - 30;} 
if (ffs3>(holder_height-10)){ffs3 = ffs3 - (ffs3-holder_height) - 30;}
if (ffs4>(holder_height-10)){ffs4 = ffs4 - (ffs4-holder_height) - 30;}
var dd = (holder_height - ffs2)*(-1); 
if (kp<dd){
kp = (holder_height - ffs2)*(-1);
}
if (kp>=ffs2) {kp=kp - (kp-ffs2);}







document.getElementById('flashback'+i.toString()+'').style.top = kp; 
document.getElementById('flashback'+i.toString()+'').innerHTML = var4;
document.getElementById('flashback'+i.toString()+'_1').style.top = kp - (ffs2 - ffs222); 







FirstBar.style.height="100%"; 
SecondBar.style.height=ffs2;
ThirdBar.style.height=ffs3;
FourthBar.style.height=ffs4;

FirstBar1.style.height="100%"; 
SecondBar1.style.height=ffs222;
ThirdBar1.style.height=ffs333;
FourthBar1.style.height=ffs444;



document.getElementById('text'+i.toString()+'_4').innerHTML = limvars[0]; 
document.getElementById('text'+i.toString()+'_3').innerHTML = limvars[1];
document.getElementById('text'+i.toString()+'_2').innerHTML = limvars[2];




}
}





window.onload = asd;


</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It must be `innerHTML`, not `innerHtml`.

Comment: That's why I like doing in in team! :) I always make some stupidity, which later, I cant see myself :) Thank you fellow! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can check following link for usage of innerHTML.Most probably you made typo.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp.

Also you can validate your javascript with following site's online validation tools.

http://www.javascriptlint.com/online_lint.php.

Best Regards

Comment: Thank you very much! :) Validator havent showed any mistakes, but it was a typo! :)